# Possible to delete data read from readable stream?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, stream, fs, fluent-ffmpeg

I have some ffmpeg processes running in order and all writing into one stream (fs.createWriteStream).

Is it possible to delete the data read through fs.createReadStream from the file?

I want to run the script 24/7 and want the stream to act like a buffer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to delete data into file?

Comment: I am opening a stream with fs.createWriteStream (file.mp3). Then I pipe the output of some ffmpeg instances into that and the file gets really big after some time which I want to prevent by deleting the content I already read out of the mp3 file (it's an audio livestream) @TGrif

Comment: So why don't you stream data directly without writing to a file ?

Comment: Because I see no possibility to "append" inputs to a running ffmpeg instance. This way I can append audio while the stream is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually "append data" to running `ffmpeg` instance - or any other writable stream. To make this possible, you need to use this option for pipe:

```
myFile.pipe(ffmpegRunner, {end: false});
```

This will tell pipe to not notify the ffmpeg that the file has ended. Then, you can switch the files once the first one ends:

```
myFile.on("end", () => {
    myFile.unpipe(ffmpegRunner);
    anotherFile.pipe(ffmpegRunner, {end: false});
});
```

You can do that even before the stream ends I guess.

Comment: To the OP, if you use this method, the files you feed ffmpeg should be either raw streams (like .mp3) or containers without global headers, like MPEG-TS.

Comment: Let me get this straight: myFile is a stream created with fs.createWriteStream() and ffmpegRunner is the ffmpeg instance?
Because [here](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#pipestream-options-pipe-the-output-to-a-writable-stream) it says ffmpegRunner.pipe(stream, options)...

Comment: Also I use .input(stream) for the instance running 24/7, how will I be able to switch files doing this?

Comment: I managed to solve this using the second example at the link I posted, just needed to fiddle around with some stuff... Thanks anyways! :)